# How to convert a String of strings to an Array/Vector of Strings in Rust

Tags: string, vector, rust

I have a string from a CSV file that contains multiple lines:

### Edit. Rust was not in the actual string.

```
header1,header2,header3
r1v1,r1v2,r1v3
r2v1,r2v2,r2v3
```

I am trying to push these into a `Vec<Vec<String>>`:

```
// the csv is raw_string
let lines = raw_string.lines();
let mut mainVec = Vec::new();

for row in lines {
    let mut childVec = Vec::new();
    let trimmed = row.trim();
    let values = trimmed.split(',').collect();
    childVec.push(values);
    mainVec.push(childVec.clone());
}
```

But I get the error

```
error[E0282]: unable to infer enough type information about `_`
 --> src/main.rs:9:13
  |
9 |         let values = trimmed.split(',').collect();
  |             ^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `_`
  |
  = note: type annotations or generic parameter binding required
```

Comment: You really want a `Vec<Vec<Vec<&str>>>`? o_O

Comment: @ildjarn Since the OP is "trying to push to a `Vec<Vec<String>>`", it seems they want a `Vec<Vec<String>>` (two `Vec`s, not three).

Comment: @user4815162342 : Ah, somehow I'd missed that bit. That said, getting rid of `childVec` should be part of the answer then.

Comment: @ildjarn No, you are completely right, sorry about that. The OP really does want a `Vec<Vec<String>>`, but their code is creating a `Vec<Vec<Vec<String>>>` with an unnecessary one-element vector in the middle.

Comment: The **true** answer is to use [the csv crate](https://crates.io/crates/csv) because parsing CSV is harder than everyone thinks it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Another solution](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=3aeb7572427ae53682b7845795112c96&version=stable), based on iterators:

```
fn main() {
    let raw_string = r"rust
header1,header2,header3
r1v1,r1v2,r1v3
r2v1,r2v2,r2v3";

    let main_vec = raw_string.lines()
                             .map(|s| s.trim().split(',').map(String::from).collect::<Vec<String>>())
                             .collect::<Vec<Vec<String>>>();

    print!("{:?}", main_vec);
}
```

As @Simon Whitehead has already said, the the only thing you need to do with `collect()` is to specify the type because this is a generic method. But it may also be deduced by the compiler itself in some circumstances.

The code above is pretty verbose about type specification: actually you may leave the `Vec`'s value type unspecified and let it be deduced by the compiler like this:

```
let main_vec = raw_string.lines()
                         .map(|s| s.trim().split(',').map(String::from).collect::<Vec<_>>())
                         .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

For more information, see the [definition of `collect()` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect).

Comment: OP wants a `Vec<Vec<String>>` rather than a `Vec<Vec<&str>>` so after the `split` there should be a `.map(String::from)` or somesuch.

Comment: @ildjarn True that seems to be my problem, I can't figure out the right spot to drop in either the `String::from()` or the `.to_string()` methods.

Comment: @mjwrazor : What Victor has at the end, plus a `.map(String::from)` after the `split`: `.map(|s| s.trim().split(',').map(String::from).collect::<Vec<_>>())`. (Other options are available e.g. `.map(|s| s.trim().split(',').map(ToString::to_string).collect::<Vec<_>>())`, but I think using `From` reads best.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to give the compiler a little hint as to what you want `values` to be.

You can say you want it to be a vector of *something*:

```
let values: Vec<_> = trimmed.split(',').collect();
```

[Working example in the playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=1e841f7520dc06d150cfc05572c70275&version=stable)

A few other notes about the code, if you're interested.

- The variable names should be `snake_case`. So the vectors should be called `main_vec` and `child_vec`.
- The `child_vec` does not need to be cloned when pushing it to the `main_vec`. Pushing it to `main_vec` transfers ownership and the loop redeclares the `child_vec` and so the compiler can guarantee nothing has been violated here.

Comment: This solution also works. [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/69085de6ed235a05cfc59e35cefa12f6)